# How to determine aspect areas for different elevation bands in a basin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am working in QGIS and have the dem rater, the vector basin boundary, the hypsometric curve and the aspect raster.

I need to determine the north, south and east-west facing areas in each of the 15 elevations bands already determined.

How can I do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if QGIS has a plugin for this, but if you have GRASS installed alongside QGIS, you can load your data into a GRASS mapset, and run the [r.slope.aspect](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.slope.aspect.html) tool.

If you feel like taking a stab at PostGIS, there is the [ST_Aspect](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_Aspect.html) function. To me, PostGIS makes the most sense in terms of dealing with multiple raster input layers, writing the queries to process/view the data, and using the final result.