# Problem with making raster from Aspect and wind direction data

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, terrain, flow, aspect

I know its not correct to ask for work flow, but I am learning by doing and now I don't know how to move on.

I'm trying to make new raster which will represent the facing sides of hill around a factory. Then I'll use wind data (.csv) file to get which of these sides are more often under blowing wind. Wind data are for 10years, and the average is north-west flow.

I was looking for some index but I couldn't find one. So is there any chance to make it with the QGIS raster calculator?

Comment: Also related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94975/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128027/